# How to get data on mongodb via logical query into node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get chat histories on mongodb.So I need use logical query in mongodb.
I have a message object.And Message have to,sender and message.
For example; in mongodb:

> -->***to:*** A ***sender:*** B ***message:*** blabla
>   -->***to:*** B ***sender:*** A ***message:*** blahblah
>   -->***to:*** C ***sender:*** A ***message:*** haha

I need only speech between A and B limit *last 20*.How can I do that in node.js?
My code:

```
function getLastMessageFor(to,sender){
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb', function(err, db) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    console.log("Connected to Database");

    db.collection('test').find($or :[ $and[{"to":to},{"sender":sender}], $and[{"to":sender},{"sender":to}]]).limit(..){})
  });
}
```

To me, ı need `{(to = toName AND sender = senderName) OR (to = senderName AND sender = toName)}.last(20)` the logic of this. But how can I do that in mongodb into nodejs.
*I need speech between A and B last 20.*

Comment: Im sorry,copy paste problem.I have written dirty code so I didn't try yet.if you understand this logic,can you write 'find()' codes completely to here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're very close, just clean it up a bit to be:

```
db.collection('test').find({$or: [
    {"to": to, "sender": sender},
    {"to": sender, "sender": to}
]}).limit(20).toArray(function(err, messages) {
    console.log(messages);
});
```

There's an implicit `$and` among fields in the same query object.